# UIView loaded from the Nib, manually calling autolayout

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, nib

I need to load a UIView from Nib and render it to a PDF (it's an Invoice). So I load the custom UIView `invoiceView` from a Nib and set it up (set various labels in it).

After setting the labels, I have to force the view to layout itself so that various UI elements resize/reposition themselves correctly.

Calling:

```
invoiceView.updateConstraints()
```

doesn't do anything.

Calling:

```
invoiceView.layoutSubviews()
```

messes everything up.

Here's what I have already tried:

1. Setting frame of the `invoiceView` (doesn't have any effect).
2. Setting the frame and adding the `invoiceView` to the current view hierarchy:

   self.view.addSubview(invoiceView)

sets up everything correctly. However I do not want to do it. I want to force the view to layout itself correctly (using the layout constraints). What am I doing wrong? What methods should I call on `invoiceView` so that it is laid out correctly without adding it to the current view hierarchy?

PS: the code has been typed from memory. please ignore typos.

Comment: If you work using autolayout forget about setting frames. To force the autolayou engine to calculate frames you should first mark as in need for a layout and later call layoutIfNeeded as kedzia wrote

Comment: I already said setting a frame doesn't do anything. I mentioned it here to avoid one liners suggesting things like this.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
invoiceView.setNeedsLayout()
invoiceView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: the above code would only call `layoutSubviews` behind the scenes. and like I said above, `layoutSubviews`  completely messes everything up. I think it's a frame/bounds issue. thanks though.

Comment: @User123 if it mess you code means that the layout that you want to apply to the view is probably not correct. The thing is different if you see ok in the view but not in the rendere PDF

Comment: the layout is correct. if it wasn't correct, it would have been messed up even when it was part of active hierarchy.